# A Technic set from ~1997 with a long grey batter box

Tags: piece-information, set-identification

I had a Technic set when I was a teen, about 1997 (by looking at the wheels, see picture). From what I remember, it was a tank truck. In its tank it was carrying 3 C batteries. In the picture, you can see the tank closed above, opened in the middle and on the right, the numbers written on the parts. The number "1-01" (or "1  01") is on the tank's three parts. The other (4351) is only on one of the three parts. **I'd like to know its set number so I could find its instructions.**

[image: You can see the tank closed above, opened in the middle and numbers written on the parts.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This battery box had been produced in two variations: [4350c01](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4350c01&in=S) (without switch) and [4350c02](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4350c02&in=S) (with switch). It doesn't seem to appear in a set you describe.

This was probably two sets. The other set has been [8865](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8865-1) since it is the only set to have [pictured wheel (part number 3739) in white](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3739&in=S).

Answer (score 5):

Looking at that part and doing a little digging, could this be the set you were thinking of. it is not a Technic set as such, it is a much older set but it seems to be the only one with a tanker and that wheel in.

Basic Building Set
Item No: 740-1
Year: 1985

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=740-1#T=I

Comment: 740 set mentioned here doesn't include pictured tire (part number 3740). Here is a list of all sets with 3740 part included: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3740&colorID=11&in=A And 8865 set is the only produced with that wheel in white: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3739&in=S

Comment: Thanks Alex, as I guess I did mixed 2 sets, since I remember the Technic set 8865! ... And that's what I was looking for!